# Number of Persons above the Mean

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this simple data set from Excel:

```
Date    Person  Amount
Jan-18  jason   1
Jan-18  fred    2
Jan-18  george  3
Feb-18  jason   10
Feb-18  fred    12
Feb-18  george  15
Feb-18  jim     25
```

I added two measures:

```
Amount = SUM( Data[Amount] )
```

and

```
Average Amount per Person = 
  AVERAGEX(
      VALUES( Data[Person]),
      [Amount]
  )
```

This works as I expect and is dynamic when I select a specific Date:

[image]

What I now want is "Number of Persons Above Average" - so in the screenshot only Jim is above 15.50 so the measure should return 1.

My attempt at this measure is this:

```
Number of Persons Above Average = 
  CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT( Data[Person] ),
      FILTER(
          Data,
          SUM( Data[Amount] ) >= [Average Amount per Person]
      )
  )
```

As you can see below it just returns the number of persons displayed - in this case 4

How do I amend the above measure to the correct `DAX` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use variables in situations like these:

```
Number of Persons Above Average =
  VAR AveragePerPerson = [Average Amount per Person]
  RETURN
      CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Person] ),
          Data[Amount] >= AveragePerPerson )
```

This way you don't have to worry about how the average measure will be computed inside of the `CALCULATE` and you don't have to use a `FILTER` function.

Comment: Ok so having the Avg inside the CALCULATE was creating a complex filter context?

Comment: That's my guess as to why it wasn't behaving as expected.